# Android: How to check if two numbers in two clicked buttons are equal (memory game)?

Tags: android, onclick, numbers, equals, buttonclick

Can someone give me a tip how to check if two numbers are equal?
I'm making memory game for practice. User clicks one button which shows one number, than he clicks another which shows second number.
How to check if those two numbers are same, beacuse if they are same they need to stay vissible, and if they are not same, they need to be hidden again.

My adapter:

```
package com.example.korisnik.assignment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Button[] buttons;
public Context c;

public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
    final ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    this.c = c;
    buttons = new Button[9];
    for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
        final int o = i;
        buttons[i] = new Button(c);
        buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.block);
        buttons[i].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300));
        buttons[i].setTag(0);
        buttons[i].setTextSize(20);
        buttons[i].setText("X");
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button btn = (Button) v;
                btn.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(o)));
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return buttons.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return buttons[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return buttons[i];
}
}
```

Comment: Add a listener class in your adapter and pass the value of buttons when they are clicked. So that you can compare the numbers when the second button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (base on what @Antonis_Lat has suggested):

**Adapter**

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private GameButton mPrevious;
    // Other necessary fields
    // ...

    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
       // Array initialisation
       // ...

        buttons = new GameButton[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new GameButton(c, "X", numbers.get(i));
            buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.block);
            buttons[i].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
            buttons[i].setTag(0);
            buttons[i].setTextSize(20);
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(ButtonAdapter.this);
        }
    }

    // The Adapter implements the interface to prevent to instantiate of a listener for each button.
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GameButton btn = (GameButton) v;
        btn.showNumber(); // Show the number on the current button
        // You can implement it like that if you want both buttons to stay displayed when similar or
        // be hidden when different
        if (mPrevious == null) {
            mPrevious = btn;
        } else {
            // If not the same
            if (!btn.isSame(mPrevious)) {
                btn.hideNumber();
                mPrevious.hideNumber();
            }
            mPrevious = null; // Reset previous button as both are now hidden/shown
        }
    }

    // Rest of the Adapter
    //... 
}
```

**Button class**

```
// Class to manage the button. It extends the AppCompatButton from the 
// Support Library but you can extend the Button class directly
public class GameButton extends AppCompatButton {
    private final String mDefaultText;
    private final int mNumber;

    public GameButton(Context context, String defaultText, int number) {
        super(context);
        mDefaultText = defaultText;
        mNumber = number;
        setText(mDefaultText); // Set the default text to the Button
    }

    public void showNumber() {
        setText(String.valueOf(mNumber));
    }

    public void hideNumber() {
        setText(mDefaultText);
    }

    public boolean isSame(@Nullable GameButton btn) {
        return btn != null && btn.getNumber() == mNumber;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return mNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. But how could I make it to show the number on second button that is clicked, and than hide them if they are not the same?

Because, now I click one button, and than other, but it doesn't show me the number on second button when they are not same.

Is there any way to make some "delay" on hiding buttons when they are not same?

Comment: Also, I should disable clicks on button that are opened already

Comment: You can use a Handler to manage the delay. Bear in mind that the user will be able to click on something else in the meantime so maybe it can creates issues. To disable your buttons you can either set `clickable` to false or set the listener to null (`btn.setOnClickListener(null);`). But in the future I'll suggest you to do some researches before asking questions as there are plenty of answers about that already. We can help you if you're blocked but we can't write the app for you.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for all. I agree,but I just wanted to finish this task as soon as possible since I'm short with time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Button[] buttons;
public Context c;
//Store previous clicked number
private String mPreviousvValue;

public ButtonAdapter(final Context c) {
    final ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    this.c = c;
    buttons = new Button[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        final int o = i;
        buttons[i] = new Button(c);
        buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.block);
        buttons[i].setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        buttons[i].setTag(0);
        buttons[i].setTextSize(20);
        buttons[i].setText("X");
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String currentValue = String.valueOf(numbers.get(o));
                Button btn = (Button) v;
                if(mPreviousvValue!=null){
                 if (mPreviousvValue.equalsIgnoreCase(currentValue)) {
                    // Show Numbers equal
                  } else {
                    // Show Numbers not equal
                  }
                }
                btn.setText(currentValue);
                mPreviousvValue = currentValue;
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return buttons.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return buttons[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return buttons[i];
}
}
```

**EDIT 1**:
Description

Add this as the global variable to store the previous value that was clicked

```
private String mPreviousvValue;
```

Then in onclick check if the current value of clicked button is equal to previous value.

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      String currentValue = String.valueOf(numbers.get(o));
      Button btn = (Button) v;
      if(mPreviousvValue!=null){
       if (mPreviousvValue.equalsIgnoreCase(currentValue)) {
          // Show Numbers equal
        } else {
          // Show Numbers not equal
         }
       }
       btn.setText(currentValue);
       mPreviousvValue = currentValue;
  }
```

**EDIT 2**:
As you asked for clearing old view when buttons values are not same

Add a public variable to store previous button position

```
private int mPreviousPos=-1;
```

Then in the on onclick store the clicked button position for the first time and when user clicks the second time,if the values are not equal get button ref from the array and clear both like shown in the code.

```
 @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String currentValue = String.valueOf(numbers.get(o));
                    Button btn = (Button) v;
                    if(mPreviousvValue!=null && mPreviousPos!=-1){
                        if (mPreviousvValue.equalsIgnoreCase(currentValue)) {

                            // Show Numbers equal
                        } else {
                            // Show Numbers not equal
                            //Clear previous button
                            Button button=buttons[mPreviousPos];
                            button.setText("X");

                        }
                    }
                    btn.setText(currentValue);
                    mPreviousvValue = currentValue;
                    mPreviousPos=o;
                }
```

Comment: @Anonymous Where do you assign previous value to the "mPreviousvValue"?

Comment: After setting button text..at the end..because for the first click it will be null.

Comment: Why is `mPreviousvValue` a String when you could store the Integer directly?

Comment: ya anything is fine..Since I saw that typecast done from Integer to String I thought not to confuse him more..So initialized with String itself

Comment: @Anonymous yea, I figured later that first time it will be null. Well let me try Your code first, than I'll get back.

Comment: How could I subtract 1 from index of Button array. Tried this:
    buttons[o-1].setText("X");
    buttons[o].setText("X"); but it doesn't work. It hides only one number...

Comment: I set button text to "X" and on click it chanes to number...when numbers are not equal i need to set those clicked buttons text back to "X". How to set text on first clicked button back to "X"

Comment: @Anonymous I am not mad, I just find 3 code comments in that chunk of code not enough to be a fair description. And instead of continuing with the "string instead of integer" casting, you could just have improved the code all together. "Not to confuse him further" is a good reason to provide a solution but also some detailed improvements. I revoke my down vote but your answer is still a lot behind getting an up vote from me.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I dint know you were another guy..seeing the comment I thought it was him who commented.Since he had asked question he would exactly knowing where I would add change if I changed something..It was rude to say answer wasn’t proper without reading.So I said that..and also If I completely optimize the code it would be diffcult for him to add my code,he has to paste evrytg..and providing solution is imp rather than optimising whole code

Comment: and also I don’t write answer just for the purpose of getting up votes..To whatever question he has posted I have given a proper solution to extent

Comment: @Mystiq I am not getting you..what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Anonymous "It was rude to say answer wasn’t proper without reading." Well, I read your answer but stopped after the first bunch of lines of code. Also please consider that this page is not only to answer the question for the OP but also for every other one that might stumble upon a similar problem but with different code. Those would have needed to compare both chunks to find the differences. If you do not care about up votes, that is up to you and totally fine. I just wanted to point out what I do and explain it.

Comment: @WarrenFaith thanks for your suggestion.But inspite of you downvoting I edited my code and added explanation..consider that also

Comment: @Anonymous maybe you should read more careful :P I explained it: "I revoke my down vote but your answer is still a lot behind getting an up vote from me."

Comment: @Mystiq you can try one thing..In the else part get the item for the particular position and then add text as "X"

Comment: @WarrenFaith Ya whatever..If I deserve people wil upvote..But I am trying to understand his problem at my best

Comment: @Mystiq  above solution is working and checked in studio

Comment: @Anonymous I tried the code, when I get first two equal numbers, first button clicked remains open, but second one still closes.

Comment: what is open and close?I coded like when two numbers are unequal first button becomes "X" and second one remains as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
First of all create a new Class

**GameButton:**

```
   public class GameButton{
                final Button button;
                boolean isOpen;
                final String hiddenNumber //may int suit for you too
                public GameButton(Button b, String number,boolean isOpen){
                  this.button=b;
                  this.number=number;
                  this.isOpen=isOpen;

        }

       public void updateState(boolean isOpen){
         this.isOpen=isOpen
     }

        public boolean isSame(GameButton gameButton){
           return this.number.equals(gameButton.number)&&!gameButton.isOpen;
        }
    }
```

Then in your adapter class you create an array of these and also you keep a variable like `GameButton lastSelectedBtn` which you set when no button is pressed and you want to remember last user choice. Then in the onClick event of any other button you just check if any of your buttons are open and if no then

```
lastSelectedButton = pressedButton;
lastSelectedButton.updateState(true)
```

If any buttons are opened (should be only one) do:

```
if(pressedButton.isSame(lastSelectedBtn)){

//bingo

}else{

// 

}
```